# Losing TextBox value when using UpdatePanel in ascx?

Tags: c#, asp.net, updatepanel

I have 2 update panel in one update panel i have a datalist and in other update panel I have a textbox with tinymce editor.

```
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server" UpdateMode="Conditional">
<ContentTemplate>
 <asp:DataList ID="dlst1" runat="server" RepeatDirection="Horizontal" CellSpacing="5" CellPadding="7" 
     DataKeyField="Id" CaptionAlign="Left" OnItemCommand="dls1_ItemCommand"                        
     OnItemDataBound="dlst1_ItemDataBound">
   <ItemTemplate>
     <asp:ImageButton ID="btnImg" OnClientClick="javascript:void(0);" 
       runat="server" ImageUrl='<%#"~/Controls/Images.ashx?FileName=" +DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "FilePath") %>' 
       CommandName="Select" OnCommand="Select_Command" 
        CommandArgument='<%# Eval("Id").ToString() ' />   
   </ItemTemplate>
</asp:DataList>
</ContentTemplate>

<asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel2" runat="server" UpdateMode="Always">
<ContentTemplate>
   <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" CssClass="tinyEditor" ClientIDMode="Static" runat="server" TextMode="MultiLine"></asp:TextBox>
</ContentTemplate>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
```

for making tinymce worked I am using

```
ScriptManager.RegisterClientScriptBlock(UpdatePanel2, this.GetType(), "init", "tinyMCE.execCommand('mceAddControl', false, '" + TextBox1.ClientID + "');", true);

var prm = Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManager.getInstance();
prm.add_endRequest(function () {
TinyMCEEditor();
});

$(function () {
TinyMCEEditor();
});
```

my TinyMCE Editor

```
 function TinyMCEEditor() {
tinyMCE.init({
    mode: "textareas",
    theme: "advanced"
});
}
```

on page load.

I am giving the text for every image, for the previous image I am storing the textbox value in a view state, suppose I have 3 images for image 1 i have given the text abcd and selected image2, so image 1 text will store in the viewstate.

on Select_Command:

```
 if (ViewState["txbtext"] != null)
            txbtext= (Hashtable)ViewState["txbtext"];
        int index1 = previouslySelectedIndex;
        if (index1 != -1)
        {
            ImageButton imgbtn= (dlst1.Items[index1].FindControl("btnImg") as ImageButton);
            if (imgbtn!= null)
            {
                string[] ImgStr = imgbtn.CommandArgument.ToString().Split(';');
                Int32 selectedId = Convert.ToInt32(Str[0]);
                if (txbtext!= null && txbtext.ContainsKey(selectedId))
                    txbtext[selectedId] = textbox.Text;
                else
                    txbtext.Add(selectedId, textbox.Text);
            }
        }
        ViewState["txbtext"] = txbtext (//this is the hashtable);
      }
```

when I was not using update panel it was working fine, but as I am using update panel I am not able to store the textbox value in viewstate,

Please someone tell me how can I fix this issue, if possible give some exp. code.

Some one plz help me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have added

```
onchange_callback: function(ed) { ed.save(); }
```

for my TInyMCE Editor its working now...

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem with it and I decided to use another editor. Have a look at CKEditor for ASP.NET http://www.ckeditor.com/download

Comment: its not the solution to change the editor, I am using TinyMCE many places how could I change my editor its client requirement also